# domain\username formatted address not resolving in Sharepoint Designer 2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, email, distribution-lists

I have a custom list on Sharepoint 2010 that has a SPD workflow attached that sends out an email to 2 Exchange distribution groups, and a small handful of individuals. This has been working fine for a long time (daily for about a year), but recently the emails have stopped working correctly.

The individuals receive the email fine, but when looking at the "To" field in outlook, the groups names are unresolved and displaying in DOMAIN\GROUP NAME format. Nobody in either groups are receiving the email.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an exchange issue. Try resetting properties of the distribution group

1. Go to Exchange Management Console -> Recipient Configuration -> Distribution group.
2. Right-click on the problem group and choose properties.
3. On the Mail Flow Settings tab, double click on Message Delivery Restrictions.
4. Uncheck the check box "Require that all senders are authenticated".

Comment: I've just given this a go, still have the same problem.

Comment: Try recycling the application pool and reopening SPD workflow